# How do I position my React hamburger menu flush at the upper right of my site?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, hamburger-menu

I want to build a hamburger menu to display on the mobile version of my React 16.13.0 app.  I'm following this tutorial -- https://www.zacwillmington.com/how-to-add-a-hamburger-menu-to-your-website/ .  So I created my nav bar component like so

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import HamburgerMenu from 'react-hamburger-menu';
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';
import './NavBar.css';

class NavBar extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            hideOrShowHambugerDropDown: 'nav'
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    }

    displayHamburgerMenu = () => {
        return (
            <HamburgerMenu
                    isOpen={this.state.open}
                    menuClicked={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
                    width={18}
                    height={15}
                    strokeWidth={1}
                    rotate={0}
                    color='black'
                    borderRadius={0}
                    animationDuration={0.5}
                />
        )
    }

    displayNavBar = () => {
        return (
            <ul className='nav'>
                    <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/add'>Add</NavLink></li>
                    <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/search'>Search</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
        )
    }

    displayMobileMenu = () => {
        return (
            <ul className='hamburgerDropDown'>
                    <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/add'>Add</NavLink></li>
                    <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/search'>Search</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='navbar'>
                { this.state.open ? this.displayMobileMenu() : null}
                {isMobile ? this.displayHamburgerMenu() : this.displayNavBar()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NavBar;
```

I'm using this stylesheet to control it ...

```
.hamburgerDropDown {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid bisque;
}

ul.hamburgerDropDown {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

However, I'm encountering a couple of problems.  The menu is not appearing flush up against the upper right of my window.  Also, the close "x" button is appearing below the menu.  How do I adjust these items?  If you're on a mobile browser you can see a demo at http://prod.chicommons.coop/ , otherwise, see below

[image]

**Edit:** If you're interested, here's the code on GitHub -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps/tree/master/client

Comment: Looks like you render the menu toggle after the menu, so without absolute/fixed positioning it'll render after the menu when it's open. Is it possible to share a runing codesandbox to address any further issues, like where you want the menu toggle physically located (upper right)? It's hard to tell in the screen shot since it looks like it's all zoomed in.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis @DrewReese.  I included a GitHub link if that's useful as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of small changes you need to do

In the hamburger dropdown class, you need to add position: absolute and top and right property

```
.hamburgerDropDown {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid bisque;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -1rem;
}
```

Secondly, in the Navbar.js component, you need to re-order the rendering of Hamburger and menu

```
 handleSelect = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  displayMobileMenu = () => {
    return (
      <ul className="hamburgerDropDown" onClick={this.handleSelect}>
        <li className="nav-link">
          <NavLink to="/add">Add</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-link">
          <NavLink to="/search">Search</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  };
render() {
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        {isMobile ? this.displayHamburgerMenu() : this.displayNavBar()}  // this rendered before menu
        {this.state.open ? this.displayMobileMenu() : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**[Working demo created based on your github project](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-franklin-k89zb?file=/src/components/NavBar.css)**

Comment: Thanks.  I believe I copied your code but I'm still seeing a couple of issues.  There seems to be a gap between the right edge of the menu and the right edge of the screen -- https://imgur.com/a/clyon88 .  Also, when I click on a menu item, the menu remains (it doesn't disappear as would be expected).

Comment: @Dave positioning the menu to slightly right or left is just css. I am sure you can do it. I will update my answer for the second part

Comment: @Dave I have updated the demo, to handle the side gap and also the closing on select on navbar menu

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like it's working well.  Going to run a few more tests but will come back and accept.

Answer (score 2):

Took a look at your GitHub. You're off to a great start and definitely headed in a good direction. That said, there's a few areas that could use some love.

### Build and Architecture

You have several functional components within your class component. I would recommend extracting those for extensibility and maintainability purposes.

> ***Note:** While making those updates you can auto-return fat arrow functions by wrapping the content with the parenthesis rather than brackets.*
>
> ***Note:** You may want to consider grouping your component specific content (`.js`, `.css`, `.test.js`, etc) into their own directories.*

**HamburgerMenu**

```js
const HamburgerMenu = () => (
    <HamburgerMenu
        isOpen={this.state.open}
        menuClicked={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        width={18}
        height={15}
        strokeWidth={1}
        rotate={0}
        color='black'
        borderRadius={0}
        animationDuration={0.5}
    />
);
```

**DesktopNav**

```js
const DesktopNav = () => (
    <ul className='nav'>
        <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/add'>Add</NavLink></li>
        <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/search'>Search</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
);
```

**MobileMenu**

```js
const MobileMenu = () => (
    <ul className='hamburgerDropDown'>
        <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/add'>Add</NavLink></li>
        <li className='nav-link'><NavLink to='/search'>Search</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
);
```

**NavBar**

You can now import the individual component pieces. Also, since, you're not doing anything but setting the `state` in the `constructor` you can actually pull that out of the constructor and set it at the class level. When implementing the new components you can just call them like any other component, rather than instantiating the function.

> _**Note:** I've also gone ahead and updated your `div` component to the more semantic and accessible `nav` component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import HamburgerMenu from 'react-hamburger-menu';
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';

import HamburgerMenu from './HamburgerMenu';
import DesktopNav from './DesktopNav';
import MobileMenu from './MobileMenu';

import './NavBar.css';

class NavBar extends Component {
    state = {
        open: false,
        hideOrShowHambugerDropDown: 'nav'
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className='navbar'>
                { this.state.open ? <MobileMenu /> : null}
                {isMobile ? <HamburgerMenu /> : <DesktopNav />}
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

### Styling

Now as to your question about styling. Due to the styling of the parent components your content is sitting right where it should be. You can either adjust your `padding` around the outside of the `header` and utilize `margin` to "push" your components where you need them. Or, as [@drew-reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) mentioned, you can utilize `position` (`absolute` or `fix`, depending what you want) to get the icon to the top right.

Also, bear in mind that Bootstrap CSS can be affecting the layout of your components. You may need to override styles set by Bootstrap in your individual components.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this thoughtful answer.  I like how you split the DesktopNav and MobileNav into two components, the only thing is this slightly increases maintainability.  Ultimately, I'd like to get to a place where I have only one list of nav titles and links and don't have to maintain it in two places.